# getting error : TypeError: tag[primaryAttributeKey].toLowerCase is not a function in react Helmet

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I am putting dynamic variable in `Helmet`, at that time i am getting this error `TypeError: tag[primaryAttributeKey].toLowerCase is not a function` , it works fine in static, here i have uploaded my code, can anyone please check my code and help me to resolve this issue ?

constant.json

```
{
    "GAME" : "talking"
}
```

constant_gmae.json

```
{
    "talking": {
        "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_URL": "https://www.googletagmanager.com/******",
        "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE": "UA-*******"
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import ConstantGame from '../../../constant.json';
import Constant from '../../../constant_game.json';

export const NavButtons = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <Helmet>
            <script>
                    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                    gtag('js', new Date()); 
                    gtag('config','{Constant[ConstantGame.GAME].GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE}' );
                </script>
            </Helmet>
        <>
    )
}
```

Comment: It should be **gtag('config', Constant[ConstantGame.GAME].GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE );**
Since, **Constant[ConstantGame.GAME].GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE** represent the value you're looking for.

Comment: thanks it is working now